# problem with flutter and post http request for authentication with nginx server with flask

Tags: flutter, dart, uwsgi, restful-authentication, flask-restful

I'm testen with writing an rest-api in Flask in combination with a mobile flutter client.
I have a problem with authentication wiht Flask-JWT.
I use ngnix and uwsgi to run the flask application on ubuntu 20.04.
With debug mode of the flask app, it runs without without problems.

With Postman it works always.
Flutter dart code:

```
      Future<String> authRequest() async {
        try {
          final HttpClient client = HttpClient();
          client.badCertificateCallback =
              ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) =>
                  true); // accept all certificat
          final Map login = {
            "username": "user",
            "password": "goodsecret",
          };
      
          final request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(ProviderBase.url + '/auth'));
          request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json");
          request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(login)));
      
          final response = await request.close();
          final reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
          final jresponse = json.decode(reply);
      
          ProviderBase.authtoken = jresponse['access_token'];
          print('token: ${ProviderBase.authtoken}');
        } catch (error) {
          print('Error: ${error.toString()}');
        }
      }
```

I get this error message (response) in flutter:

```
      "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
      <title>400 Bad Request</title>
      <h1>Bad Request</h1>
      <p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>"
```

Maybe someone has an idea?
I uses at the moment self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
it's the missing header content length. With the webserver it's necessary.

this works for me:

```
...
final body = utf8.encode(json.encode(login));
request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.contentLengthHeader, body.length.toString());
request.add(body);
...
```